# What are "ASCII-based tools"? (from 3.3 of the JLS)

Tags: java, jls

Chapter 3.3: "The Java programming language specifies a standard way of transforming a program written in Unicode into ASCII that changes a program into a form that can be processed by ASCII-based tools."

I think it is referring directly to the JDK tool: "native2ascii".  However, the language is so vague, I couldn't understand what they were talking about.

Comment: Any third party tool that can process only ASCII files, for example line/word counters.

Comment: Could you give me a real world example.

Comment: According to its info, [wc](http://www.linfo.org/wc.html) prefers [plain text](http://www.linfo.org/plain_text.html), which is almost synonym of ASCII.